# Show the option selected after $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form & a table and the user can calculate the sum by clicking an icon. For staying at same page I use    `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`    . 
The amount can be selected from option fields. My problem is now: If the user select f.e. '20' as amount, he click the icon and get the sum caculated, how to display then the '20' as selected in the option field?
Here my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['lvl4order'])){
$lvl4ord = $_POST['lvl4order'];
} ?>
```

This is the best solution I have, but shows the values double in 2 lines in option value:

```
    <form name="calculation" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>">
<table>
<td>
<?php
if ($product['lvl4'] > 1)
    {
    echo "<select name='lvl4order'>";
$span = range(1,$product['lvl4']);
    foreach ($span as $range) {
    $txt = $range == 1 ? 'Box' : 'Boxes';
    echo "<option value='$range' >$range $txt</option>";
    echo "<option selected='selected'>$lvl4ord</option>";
    if (++$range == 50) break;
}
echo "</select>";
}
else {}
?>
</td>
<td><INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="../images/calculator.png" NAME="calc">
</td>
    </table></form>
```

If I try something like this, it does not work:

```
echo "<option value='$range' if($range= '$lvl4ord'){ selected='selected'} >$range $txt</option>";
```

How to fix this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all wrong. You can't put an `if` statement in the middle of `echo`, you need to use a ternary expression. You have to use `==` to compare, not `=`. And if you put a variable inside single quotes, it won't be evaluated.

echo "$range $txt";

Comment: I know that I have to clean up my code (compare with ==,variable without single quotes), but during testing and in my test enviroment, it´s running.
Last line of code I posted is just a 'try' to integrate all in 1 line. As wrote, it does not work (    if    inside the     echo    ). I'll try it with a ternary expression.